# How to show text selection with left and right cursors?

Tags: android, android-edittext

There is the **EditText** in my app. When the user clicks on it, all the text is highlighted. I want to show left and right cursors and hide context menu with the appearance of the selection (like on the screenshot).

[image: regular text selection]

How can I do this?